# Comparing Ip addresses in php not working

Tags: php, ip

I'm trying to compare the user's IP to allowed IP's. It's saying that my IP isn't allowed when it echos *`97.103.49.59You do not have permission to do that.`*

I'm trying to compare them like so:

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
echo "$ip_address";
if(ip_adress=="97.103.49.59") { 
header('Location: Blog.php');
} else {
echo "You do not have permission to do that.";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(ip_adress=="97.103.49.59") {
```

should read

```
if($ip_address=="97.103.49.59") {
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
 if($ip_address=="97.103.49.59")
```

you can also allow or deny specific range

```
$start = ip2long("97.103.49.1");
$end = ip2long("97.103.49.255");
$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if ($ip >= $start && $ip <= $end) {
    // In range
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the $ in front of ip_adress.

```
if($ip_address=="97.103.49.59")
```

should do the trick.

Comment: again, address is spelt wrong

Comment: thanks, I also mis-spelt address lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($ip_adress=="97.103.49.59") {
```

You forgot `$` there..